# How to express the integrands of lengths, areas, (hyper)volumes in a general way?

Tags: matrices, determinant, closed-form, jacobian

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^n$ where $0<k\leq n$ are integers. Let $Q$ be a length $\binom{n}{k}$ vector consisting of the determinants for all $k\times k$ submatrices of the jacobian $J$ of $f$.

Is it possible to express $||Q||_2$ elegantly in terms of $J$ using matrix algebra?

E.g. if
$n=3$, $k=1$ then $||Q||_2$ is everywhere expressed as the norm of the gradient.
$n=3$, $k=2$ then $||Q||_2$ is everywhere expressed as the norm of a cross product.
$n=3$, $k=3$ then $||Q||_2$ is everywhere expressed as the absolute value of a determinant.

I don't like this diversity of expressions for similar concepts, but so far I could only eliminate it using words (first two lines).

Comment: You can always express it as a determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I see now $\ ||Q||_2 = \sqrt{\det(J^TJ)}$.

**Edit:** I just encountered the Cauchy–Binet formula and noted that the above equility is a special case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/873224)

Comment: @Krish By "author" do you mean the one who asked the question (me)?! Also I don't understand why this doens't answer the question

Comment: Why don't you explain a bit of your answer (e.g. how do you come to the conclusion)? Technically speaking, this indeed gives an answer to your question. But just sit back for a moment and think: your question and answer is now part of MSE, and anyone else can have the same question as you had. It might be possible that she/he will be directed to this question and her/his question will be marked as "duplicate". What if she/he can't understand this answer? She/he will be helpless, as she/he can't ask the same question again. (continued...)

Comment: (continued...) I leave it to your responsibility to do whatever you think is best for you. This site is based on "Individual Social Responsibility". I'll leave it to you, again, to think about it.